# certificate invalid issue on a Mac OS X using chrome

Tags: certificate, macos

I am trying to access a website on chrome on a Mac OS X where it shows me the error that the certificate is invalid and the connection is insecure.  However, I can access the same website using chrome on windows and ubuntu (different computer).  This Mac laptop was used overseas over the last few months.  I am wondering if something was installed on the Mac which might be intercepting traffic (and perhaps sending it to a different computer).  I plan on taking this to a Apple store to get it checked out.  Are there any steps I can take to further troubleshoot and perhaps solve this issue (I know how to add an exception in chrome to visit the site but that's not what I'm trying to achieve).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: More info plz! What does safari say? What does Firefox say? What does the SSLLabs.com report say? Screenshots?

Comment: will check and update shortly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Symantec/Verisign CA appearing as an invalid authority?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/why-is-symantec-verisign-ca-appearing-as-an-invalid-authority)

Comment: Download the certificate and place it in the OS X certificate store.